# Render Errors w/ Rigged Characters

Tags: modeling, animation, mesh, rigify, clipping

having a strange issue with different rigged characters when rendering an animation. There aren't any issues with a Workbench render, but when doing a textured Cycles render, these strange lines jut out of the rigged mesh, almost like it's being pulled at different spots.
Nothing in the scene has a collision modifier, and the rig isn't parented to any other objects. Screenshots of the issue are included - I'm using a basic Rigify rig customized to fit my character's proportions. If anyone knows anything I can try, it would be a huge help!
The issue persists across multiple different rigs, including those downloaded from Mixamo.

[image: img1Textured]
[image: img1Wrkbnch]
[image: img2Textured]
[image: img2Wrkbnch]
[image: img1Circ]
[image: img2Circ]

Answer (score 0):

Update: It was an issue with motion blur, I knew it couldn't be something to do with the mesh / rig because of the Workbench render so I just tried out as many different render settings as possible.